# pyspark write to wasb blob storage container

Tags: python-3.x, azure, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a Ubuntu instance to run a calculation of azure using a N-series instance. After the calculation I try to write to a Azure blob container using the wasb like URL

```
wasb://containername/path
```

I am trying to use the pyspark command

```
sparkSession.write.save('wasb://containername/path', format='json', mode='append')
```

But I receive a Java io exception from spark saying it doesn't support a wasb file system. I was wondering if anyone knows how to write to a wasb address while not using a HDInsight instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done it with the `pyspark` but here is how I did using scala and spark.

Add the dependency in sbt

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure" % "2.7.3"
```

Then define the file system to be used in the underlying `Hadoop` configurations.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("read azure storage").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.yourAccount.blob.core.windows.net", "yourKey ")

val baseDir = "wasb[s]://BlobStorageContainer@yourUser.blob.core.windows.net/"
```

Now write the dataframe to blob container

```
resultDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json(baseDir + outputPath)
```

Hope this is helpful [here](https://sktechie.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/how-to-data-from-azure-blob-storage-with-apache-spark/) was the working program

Comment: The link you have shared shows only reading data from azure and not writing.

Comment: Once you add the file system configs you should able to read and write. There is example above to write the dataframe.