# Write data from pyspark to azure blob?

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, blob

I want to write dataframe from pyspark to azure blob? Any suggestions or code how to do it?

I have location and key of blob

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKy55.png)

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes in approach it helps but facing issue while writing the data as csv. Please find the link for the error in question part.

Answer (score 2):

You could follow this [tutorial](https://luminousmen.com/post/azure-blob-storage-with-pyspark) to connector your spark dataframe with Azure Blob Storage.

Set connection info:

```
session.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    "<your-storage-account-access-key>"
)
```

Then write data into blob storage:

```
sdf = session.write.parquet(
    "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<prefix>"
)
```

Also,you could refer to this case:[pyspark write to wasb blob storage container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410436/pyspark-write-to-wasb-blob-storage-container)

Comment: I tried the approach which you mentioned above and getting exception as "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The String is not a valid Base64-encoded string."

Comment: I have attached a screenshot on the error message i got below the question. Please have a look on it and can you tell me what the exact error is?