# Saving Pyspark Dataframe to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, pyspark

I am migrating a proof of concept from AWS / EMR to Azure.

It’s written in python and uses Spark, Hadoop and Cassandra on AWS EMR and S3. It calculates Potential Forward Exposure for a small set of OTC derivatives.

I have one roadblock at present: How do I save a pyspark dataframe to Azure storage?

In AWS / S3 this is quite simple, however I’ve yet to make it work on Azure. I may be doing something stupid!

I've tested out writing files to blob and file storage on Azure, but have yet to find pointers to dataframes.

On AWS, I currently use the following:

```
npv_dataframe.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(output_dir + '/exposure_scenarios/' + str(counterparty))
```

where output_dir is in the format `s3://s3_bucket_name/directory_name`

I set up a Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account and container. I have enabled public access to it.

I have explored various methods e.g:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-python
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-python?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json
- https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/data-import/azure-blob-store.html
- [Write data from pyspark to azure blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56983295/write-data-from-pyspark-to-azure-blob) (I believe this is old and that hadoop 3.2.1 comes with abfs support)

Some of these examples use a file-upload pattern but what I wanted was a direct save from a pyspark dataframe.

The test code I used was:

```
import traceback
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

try:

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    conf.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.key.#myaccount#.blob.core.windows.net', '#mykey#')
    df = spark.createDataFrame(["10", "11", "13"], StringType()).toDF("age")
    df.show()
    df \
        .coalesce(1) \
        .write.format('csv') \
        .option('header', True) \
        .mode('overwrite') \
        .save('wasbs://#mycontainer#@#myaccount#.blob.core.windows.net/result_csv')
    print("Hadoop version: " + spark.sparkContext._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion())
except Exception as exp:
    print("Exception occurred")
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

The example above fails at the `df.write` - the error is

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem not found
```

I receive the same error when using spark-submit

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.1,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.3 ./test.py
```

I believe this may be a version compatibility problem. I noticed that the hadoop.jars in pyspark were all version 2.7.4, whereas I was referencing the 3.2.1 installation.

I am / was using:

Java 8 (1.8.0_265)
Spark 3.0.0
Hadoop 3.2.1
Python 3.6
Ubuntu 18.04

I ensured all hadoop jars in the Spark directory were the same as in the Hadoop jar directory.

After following another stack trace error I updated the command to: spark-`submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.1,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.5 test.py`

I then received a different Java error, which looks like a problem with the key??

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, java.lang.Class)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:45)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.getAccountKeyFromConfiguration(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createAzureStorageSession(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1078)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:524)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Also, after adding the Azure account secure key to the hadoop config, if I try:

```
hdfs dfs -ls wasbs://CONTAINER@ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/
```

I receive the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found`

Any help appreciated! Bit stuck for ideas. It also seems that, relative to AWS, there are few solved posts about Azure storage / Dataframe issues.

Comment: If you use Azure blob, the path should be like `wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory-name>`.

Comment: Hi there Jim - I should have mentioned that I tried this format for baseDir when I used wasbs protocol as outlined above. It throws the same error "No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs. I double checked just now. All this makes me think I am missing a package / config for Azure blob storage. Perhaps a jar needed when Spark starts up as per the spark-submit example above?

Comment: Please add `sessio.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")` to py file then use `spark-submit` command run again.

Comment: Hi Jim,

I amended the test code as per above. The error I now get is "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem not found"

Any further ideas?

Comment: It seems that you miss ` hadoop-azure.jar`?

Comment: Thanks again. I added more detail above - making some progress. Perhaps it's a version compatibility problem?

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing the storage account to a Blobstorage type, rather than Storage Gen2. Windows Azure Storage Blob (WASB) driver [is unsupported with Data Lake Storage Gen2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues#windows-azure-storage-blob-wasb-driver-unsupported-with-data-lake-storage-gen2)

Comment: How exactly do you change the account type?

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, we can use the package `com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.3` to upload files to Azure blob in spark.

For example

I am using

Java 8 (1.8.0_265) Spark 3.0.0 Hadoop 3.2.0 Python 3.6.9 Ubuntu 18.04

My code

```
import traceback
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

try:
     
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    conf.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.key.jimtestdiag924.blob.core.windows.net', '')
    df = spark.createDataFrame(["10", "11", "13"], StringType()).toDF("age")
    df.show()
    df \
      .coalesce(1) \
      .write.format('csv') \
      .option('header', True) \
      .mode('overwrite') \
      .save('wasbs://testupload@<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/result_csv')  
    print("Hadoop version: " + spark.sparkContext._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion())      
except Exception as exp:
    print("Exception occurred")
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

My command

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.3  spark.py
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi there - sorry, other work priorities! Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, I still get the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.StreamCapabilities" error. I also reinstalled everything from scratch and it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @FSmi Please ensure that  the version of `hadoop-azure`  is the same as version of the hadoop- JARs

Comment: While searching for solutions to the StreamCapabilities error I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310416/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-fs-streamcapabilities-while-reading-s3-d and so tried to include hadoop-common in the spark packages. This leads to a different error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, java.lang.Class)'".

Comment: As you suggest, I believe the problem may be incompatible jars as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242548/spark-uses-s3a-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Hi Jim - I ensured all hadoop jars are consistent across Hadoop, Spark & Ivy. See new error above.

Comment: I absolutely confirm that the hadoop jars need to have the same version. Once done, now it works